# AJAX search on post pages by custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, search, ajax

I'm having an issue creating an ajax search on my single post pages. I need to limit the search results to the custom post types "fod_videos" and "post" and category 12. My issue is the search is returning all the posts under those filters and not taking the search value. I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious but I can' figure it out. Here's my setup.

```
<div class="panel">
  <h2>Search Videos</h2>
  <div id="my-search">
   <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://myurl.com/" >
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
   </form>
  </div>
</div>

add_action('wp_ajax_wpa5000_search', 'wpa5000_search');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpa5000_search', 'wpa5000_search');
function wpa5000_search(){
  global $wp_query;
  $search = $_POST['search_val'];
  $args = array(
    's' => $search,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'cat' => 12, 
    'post_type' => array( 'post','fod_videos'  )
  );
  $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  get_template_part( 'video-search-results' );

  exit;
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa56343_scripts', 100 );
function wpa56343_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_script(
    'wpa56343_script',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/libs/search.js?ver=1.0',
    array( 'jquery' ),
    null,
    false
 );
 wp_localize_script(
    'wpa56343_script',
    'WPaAjax',
    array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    )
 );
}
```

// search.php

```
$(document).ready(function($){
 $('#searchsubmit').click(function(e){
    var $panel = $(this).closest(".panel");
    $panel.empty();
    e.preventDefault();
    var search_val=$("#s").val();
    $.post(
        WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
        {
            action : 'wpa5000_search',
            search_val : search_val
        },
        function( response ) {
            $panel.append( response );
        }
    );
 });
});
```

//video-search-results.php

```
<?php
 while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
   //STUFF
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Is $wp_query an actual WP_Query object?

Comment: @BrianFegter I'm not sure I get what you mean. You know it's weird I use this exact formula on my index page to get ajax search results and it works fine. It just isn't pulling the search_val. I tried printing $search but it returns nothing.

Comment: AJAX actions don't have $wp_query defined because there is no context other than the $_POST data.

Comment: What's making it work from my index page? I use it to replace the default loop with the search results and it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `'cat' => 12` and `$wp_query` use `'category_name' => slug` and [`get_posts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_posts/).

Here is a basic example how it works:

#### PHP

```php
add_action( 'wp_loaded', array ( 'T5_Ajax_Search', 'init' ) );

/**
 * Ajaxify the search form.
 */
class T5_Ajax_Search
{
    /**
     * The main instance. You can create further instances for unit tests.
     * @type object
     */
    protected static $instance = NULL;

    /**
     * Action name used by AJAX callback handlers
     * @type string
     */
    protected $action = 't5_ajax_search';

    /**
     * Handler for initial load.
     *
     * @wp-hook wp_loaded
     * @return void
     */
    public static function init()
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor. Registers the actions.
     *
     *  @wp-hook wp_loaded
     *  @return object
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $callback = array ( $this, 'search' );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_'        . $this->action,        $callback );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $this->action, $callback );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array ( $this, 'register_script' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Callback for AJAX search.
     *
     * @wp-hook wp_ajax_t5_ajax_search
     * @wp-hook wp_ajax_nopriv_t5_ajax_search
     * @return void
     */
    public function search()
    {
        $args  = array ( 's' => $_POST['search_term'] );
        $args  = apply_filters( 't5_ajax_search_args', $args );
        $posts = get_posts( $args );
        if ( $posts )
        {
            $this->render_search_results( $posts );
        }
        else
        {
            print '<b>nothing found</b>';
        }
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * Create markup from $posts
     *
     * @param array $posts Array of post objects
     * @return void
     */
    protected function render_search_results( $posts )
    {
        print '<ul class="t5-ajax-search-results">';

        foreach ( $posts as $post )
        {
            printf(
                '<li><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>',
                get_permalink( $post->ID ),
                esc_html( $post->post_title )
            );
        }
        print '</ul>';
    }

    /**
     * Register script and local variables.
     *
     * @wp-hook wp_enqueue_scripts
     * @return void
     */
    public function register_script()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            't5-ajax',
            #plugins_url( __FILE__ ) . '/search.js',
            plugins_url( 'search.js', __FILE__ ),
            array ( 'jquery' ),
            NULL,
            TRUE
        );

        wp_localize_script(
            't5-ajax',
            'T5Ajax',
            array(
                'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                'action'  => $this->action
            )
        );
    }
}
```

#### JavaScript `search.js`

```js
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    // search filed
    var $s = $( '#s' );
    // the search form
    var $sForm = $s.closest( 'form' );
    console.log( $sForm );
    $sForm.on( 'submit', function( event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post(
            T5Ajax.ajaxurl,
            {
                action:     T5Ajax.action,
                search_term: $s.val()
            },
            function( response ) {
                // just append the result to the search form.
                $sForm.append( response );
            }
        );
    });
});
```

#### Restricting the search

```php
add_filter( 't5_ajax_search_args', 'restrict_t5_search' );

function restrict_t5_search( $args )
{
    $args['post_type'] = array ( 'post', 'fod_videos' );
    $args['category_name']       = 'category-slug';
    return $args;
}
```

---

Instead of my `$this->render_search_results( $posts );` you can also load a template from your theme and use the `$posts` array in a more sophisticated result. :)

Answer (score 3):

I got the original code working, but with the custom post type (without the categories). Add a hidden input in your form with your post type like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="fod_videos" />
```