# Auto Complete Search

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, search

I have a post type name jobs and I created a few custom taxonomies named 'region', 'job_type' now I want to create a search that uses the custom taxonomies and jobs post types. I want the search to have an auto-complete feature. Any help or direction would be great.

Comment: What have your research and coding attempts thrown up so far? [ask]

Comment: I have tried [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62720/ajax-search-on-post-pages-by-custom-post-type) but didn't work for me

Comment: there is no such thing as "don't work" in software, only "unexpected result".... please edit your question and include your actual code and explain what is it that you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-search-lite/)

Comment: How did this plugin solve your issue? Can you expand more on your answer please?

Comment: Just Install and configure the plugin, does exactly what I wanted it. 
The plugin is very easy to configure and uses shortcode

Comment: If you can tell me how to code it, It'll be amazing.